# UIAlertView takes too long when using inside NSURLSession

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertview, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am using `NSURLSession` to get some information from my server.
After i get the data, i show it in a `UIAlertView`, but it takes too long to show. I print the data with the `NSLog` and it prints it almost instantly... So what is happening? Does the method `dataTaskWithRequest` is not asynchronous? Why it takes so much time to pop up the alert view?

```
NSURLSession *session;
session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[DRESSABLE_IP stringByAppendingString:@"index.php"]];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:CONNECTION_CACHEPOLICY  timeoutInterval:CONNECTION_TIMEOUT];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest 
completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *total = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:total delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
 }];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All UI activity must be done in the main queue.

```
NSURLSession *session;
session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[DRESSABLE_IP stringByAppendingString:@"index.php"]];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:CONNECTION_CACHEPOLICY  timeoutInterval:CONNECTION_TIMEOUT];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest 
completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *total = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:total delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
});
 }];
```